# angularjs $location.path('/home') not redirecting to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on login authentication in my MVC application. I am trying for so long with this issue. After my login is success i want to redirect to home page, but my code $location.path('/home') does nothing. And later I found it is always going to my default path which is given in my routeprovider in app.js.

please anyone suggest me what mistake I have made..

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
"toastr",
"ui.bootstrap",
"ngRoute",
"datatables",
"ngMaterial",
"ngMessages",
"material.svgAssetsCache"
]);

app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    console.log('$routeProvider' + JSON.stringify($routeProvider));
    console.log('$locationProvider' + $locationProvider);
    //return
    $routeProvider.when("/login",
        {
            redirectTo: "/login"
        }).when("/Home",
        {
            redirectTo: "~/Home/Index/"
            //controller: "MyCtrl"
        }).when("/user",
        {
            redirectTo: "/User/"
        }).when("/adduser",
        {
            redirectTo: "/User/User"
        }).when("/role",
        {
            redirectTo: "/Role/"
        }).when("/addrole",
        {
            redirectTo: "/Role/AddRole"
        }).when("/settings",
        {
            redirectTo: "/Settings/"
        }).when("/Editsettings",
        {
            redirectTo: "/Settings/Edit/"
        }).when("/uploadData",
        {
            redirectTo: "/UploadDataFile/"
        }).otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/Test/Index'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    }).hashPrefix('!'); //Remove the '#' from URL.   
}])
```

Login.js

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, $window) {
$scope.ddlDomain = [ 'AS', 'EU', 'LA'];
$scope.Domain = $scope.ddlDomain[0].value;

// send to your controller
$scope.LoginClick = function () {
    var User = {
        UserId: $scope.UserId,
        Password: $scope.Password,
        Domain: $scope.Domain
    }

    $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/Login/SSOLogin",
        data: { 'user': User }
    }).then(function (response) {

        if ((response.data.Message == "") || (response.data.Message == null)) {                               
            $location.path('/Home');

            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                //$digest or $apply
                $scope.$apply();    
            }
        } else {
            $scope.errormsg = response.data.Message;
        }
        // handle success here
    }, function (response) {
        console.log("err" + response.data);
            // handle error here
        });
}
});
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors?  Your error handler is a no-op. In addition, are you sure the response conditional is met in order to hit the `$location.path('/Home')`?

Comment: @Phix:  yeah, the response condition is met. In my routeconfig, it is always hitting the "otherwise" condition.

Comment: Why so many `redirectTo`?

Comment: @Phix, based on different conditions I have to redirect to different pages. that's why? Even when I used templateurl, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This config:

```
$routeProvider
  .when("/login", {
    redirectTo: "/login"
  })
  .when("/Home", {
    redirectTo: "~/Home/Index/"
    //controller: "MyCtrl"
  })
```

It looks like you're redirecting to `/Home` as expected, but your're redirecting immediately to `~/Home/Index/`, which doesn't exist, thus the third redirect to your `otherwise` block.

**Edit**

Addressing your comments:

> But I have the page Home/index.
>
> Oh I'm sorry. I have tried even after removing ~, then also not working

My dude... **`/Home/Index/` is not a defined route in the above config.**

Per this route config:

```
$routeProvider.when("/Home", {
    redirectTo: "~/Home/Index/"
    //controller: "MyCtrl"
})
```

You are redirecting from `/Home` to a **non-existent** route called `/Home/Index`, which again, is not defined in the configuration you posted.

Here's what Angular is saying:

```
`/Home` => 
    "Ok, when the user hits this route, 
    I need to redirect them to `/Home/Index` because 
    that's what I was told to do." 
`/Home/Index` => "Hmm, I don't see that route configured. Exiting. 
 => Fall back to my `otherwise` block."
```

You said

> But I have the page Home/index.

What do you mean by this?  You have a document called "index" inside of a directory called "Home"?  AngularJS doesn't work like this.

Comment: I'm new to angularjs, that's why I couldn't follow your answer. could you please explain your answer ?.  What is actually wrong there? what should I change?

Comment: What you're saying here is "When the user requests to go to `/Home`, redirect them to `~/Home/Index`.  Since `~/Home/Index` doesn't exist, AngularJS defers to the `otherwise` block, hence the reason you always hit the default path.

Comment: But I have the page Home/index.

Comment: Not according to what you've posted.  `~` is not a valid character for routing, nor is `/Home/Index/` defined in your routes.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I have tried even after removing ~, then also not working